# Input change event calling wrong function but logs the correct input event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, input

I have an order form with billing and shipping information and want to validate each input with their respective functions.

All of the inputs are calling their correct validations except for one. I'm assuming it's because it has a similar attribute name to other inputs being validated by a different function.

How do I get the input validation working correctly?

I've tried addressing the issue during the input change event by looking for the inputs ID rather than the inputs name, but it still calls the ValidateText function rather than the ValidateZipCode function. Console.logging from inside the ValidateText function shows the correct order[shipping_address_attributes][zipcode] input

```
if (orderForm) {
  orderForm.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    validateOrderForm(event.target);
  });
};

function validateOrderForm(field) {
  if (ValidateInput(field)) {
    setValidStyles(field);
console.log("Success: " + field.value);
  } else {
setInvalidStyles(field);
console.log("Failing: " + field.value);
  }
}

function ValidateEmail(input) {
  let reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  console.log("Hello from: Email");
  return reg.test(input);
}

function ValidateText(input) {
  console.log("Hello from: Text");
  return (input.value.length > 0 && input.value.length < 121 && isNaN(input.value) && input.value != "");
}

function ValidateTextWithNumbers(input) {
  console.log("Hello from: TextWithNumbers");
  return (input.value.length > 0 && input.value.length < 121 && input.value != "");
}

function ValidateZipCode(input) {
  console.log("Hello from: Zipcode");
  let reg = /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/;
  return reg.test(input);
}

function ValidateInput(input) {
  if (input.name == "order[shipping_address_attributes][city]" || "order[shipping_address_attributes][state]" || "order[first_name]" || "order[last_name]") {
    return ValidateText(input);
  } else if (input.name == "order[email]") {
return ValidateEmail(input);
  } else if (input.name == "order[recipe_name]" || "order[shipping_address_attributes][address_one]" || "order[shipping_address_attributes][address_two]") {
return ValidateTextWithNumbers(input);
  } else if (input.name == "order[shipping_address_attributes][zipcode]") {
return ValidateZipCode(input);
  } else {
console.log("Input didnt match required input names.");
return false;
  }
}


<div class="order-field">
  <%= form.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "first name", class: "input-small green-input required" %>
</div>      
<div class="order-field">
  <%= form.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "last name", class: "input-small green-input required" %>
</div>

<%= form.fields_for :shipping_address do |builder| %>
  <div class="order-field">
    <%= builder.text_field :address_one, placeholder: "address 1", class: "input-small green-input required" %>
  </div>
  <div class="order-field">
    <%= builder.text_field :address_two, placeholder: "address 2", class: "input-small green-input" %>
  </div>
  <div class="order-field">
<%= builder.text_field :city, placeholder: "city", class: "input-small green-input required" %>
  </div>
  <div class="order-field">
<%= builder.text_field :state, placeholder: "state", class: "input-small green-input required" %>
  </div>
  <div class="order-field">
    <%= builder.text_field :zipcode, placeholder: "zipcode", class: "input-small green-input required" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="order-field">
  <%= form.text_field :email, placeholder: "email", class: "input-small green-input required" %>
</div>
```

The form is for an Order model that has_one shipping_address.
The form submits correctly and works correctly with the database validations but on the client side I'm expecting the order[shipping_address_attributes][zipcode] input to call the ValidateZipCode function, but it's actually calling the ValidateText function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t string or statements together like this:

input.name == "order[shipping_address_attributes][city]" || "order[shipping_address_attributes][state]" || "order[first_name]" || "order[last_name]"

What that’s actually doing is:

```
input.name == "order[shipping_address_attributes][city]"
```

OR

```
"order[shipping_address_attributes][state]"
```

OR ... etc

The point is that the second string onwards are not being compared to input.name. JS is evaluating `"order[shipping_address_attributes][state]"` to a Boolean and because it’s not blank it returns true.

You either need to do `input.name == "order[shipping_address_attributes][city]" || input.name ==  "order[shipping_address_attributes][state]” || ...etc`

Or a little cleaner:

[ "order[shipping_address_attributes][city]", "order[shipping_address_attributes][state]", "order[first_name]", "order[last_name]”].includes(input.name);

Hope that helps

Comment: That makes a lot of sense i'm going to fix it in a bit n update with results here n see if it also fixes the zipcode input problem :) thank you I'll mark yours the answer once I update the code.

Comment: You're the man~ Everything is working smoothly now. Many thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, happy coding!